# ChartJs - Round borders on a doughnut chart with multiple datasets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, chart.js

I have a regular Chartjs doughnut chart with multiple datasets, using this code for the dataset:

```
datasets: 
    [
        {
            label: 'Bugs',
            data: [ 60 , 6.6666666666667 , 33.333333333333 ],
            backgroundColor: ['#25CFE4', '#92E7F1', '#eeeeee'],
        }, {
            label: 'Fixes',
            data: [ 60 , 0.44444444444444 , 39.555555555556 ],
            backgroundColor: ['#514463', '#8C75AB', '#eeeeee'],
        }, {
            label: 'Redesigns',
            data: [
            33.333333333333 , 10.37037037037 , 56.296296296296 ],
            backgroundColor: ['#1B745F', '#40C1A0', '#eeeeee'],
        }
    ]
};
```

I am trying to implement rounded edges on the scales, I manage to make the first one round, but no luck with the others.

Basically, this is what I have now

[image]

And this is what I am trying to achieve (sorry for the poor photoshop)

[image]

I don't mind if the start of the scale is also round or the grey area (which I painted grey just to give the impression of something not yet filled) gas round edges too.

Thanks

Comment: You will probably need to do something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582555/how-to-put-rounded-corners-on-a-chart-js-bar-chart

Comment: Or even better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934967/chart-js-doughnut-with-rounded-edges

Comment: You can use the pluginService to do this.Try this....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384092/chart-js-doughnut-with-rounded-edges-and-text-centered

Comment: I have tried both your comments before. Both only makes the outer-most scale round, and only the largest bar :(

Comment: @fsenna Did you find anything useful. I am facing same issue, only outer is getting fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Made a few more adjustments and finally got it.This does exactly what you want:

```
    Chart.pluginService.register({
        afterUpdate: function (chart) {
                var a=chart.config.data.datasets.length -1;
                for (let i in chart.config.data.datasets) {
                    for(var j = chart.config.data.datasets[i].data.length - 1; j>= 0;--j) { 
                        if (Number(j) == (chart.config.data.datasets[i].data.length - 1))
                            continue;
                        var arc = chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data[j];
                        arc.round = {
                            x: (chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2,
                            y: (chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2,
                            radius: chart.innerRadius + chart.radiusLength / 2 + (a * chart.radiusLength),
                            thickness: chart.radiusLength / 2 - 1,
                            backgroundColor: arc._model.backgroundColor
                        }
                    }
                    a--;
                }
        },

        afterDraw: function (chart) {
                var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
                for (let i in chart.config.data.datasets) {
                    for(var j = chart.config.data.datasets[i].data.length - 1; j>= 0;--j) { 
                        if (Number(j) == (chart.config.data.datasets[i].data.length - 1))
                            continue;
                        var arc = chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data[j];
                        var startAngle = Math.PI / 2 - arc._view.startAngle;
                        var endAngle = Math.PI / 2 - arc._view.endAngle;

                        ctx.save();
                        ctx.translate(arc.round.x, arc.round.y);
                        console.log(arc.round.startAngle)
                        ctx.fillStyle = arc.round.backgroundColor;
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        //ctx.arc(arc.round.radius * Math.sin(startAngle), arc.round.radius * Math.cos(startAngle), arc.round.thickness, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                        ctx.arc(arc.round.radius * Math.sin(endAngle), arc.round.radius * Math.cos(endAngle), arc.round.thickness, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();
                        ctx.restore();
                    }
                }
        },
    });
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tgyxmkLj/1/

Comment: Thank you so very much. That is awesome.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is an older thread, but I have a similar design problem using `"chart.js": "^3.9.1"` and `"react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1"`. My solution was to add 2 "caps" to each arc: one serves as the rounded-spacing between each arcs and one is the rounded cap. Here's my full code with typings:

```
import {
  ArcElement as ChartJSArcElement,
  ArcOptions as ChartJSArcOptions,
  ArcProps as ChartJSArcProps,
  Color as ChartJSColor,
  Chart as ChartJS,
  ChartData as ChartJSData,
  DoughnutController as ChartJSDoughnutController,
  Element as ChartJSElement,
  Plugin as ChartJSPlugin,
} from "chart.js";
import { AnyObject as ChartJSAnyObject } from "chart.js/types/basic";
import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";

ChartJS.register(ChartJSArcElement);

const colors: ChartJSColor[] = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow"];
const data: ChartJSData<"doughnut"> = {
  labels: colors,
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [500, 100, 300, 250],
      backgroundColor: colors,
      borderWidth: 0,
    },
  ],
};

interface Round {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  radius: number;
  arcColor: ChartJSColor;
}

type CustomElement =
  | (ChartJSElement<
      ChartJSAnyObject | ChartJSArcProps,
      ChartJSAnyObject | ChartJSArcOptions
    > & {
      round?: Round;
    })
  | (ChartJSArcElement<ChartJSArcProps, ChartJSArcOptions> & {
      round?: Round;
    });

const plugins: ChartJSPlugin<"doughnut">[] = [
  {
    id: "arcCaps",
    afterUpdate: function (chart) {
      // we only expect 1 dataset
      const { data, controller } = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
      const { outerRadius, innerRadius } =
        controller as ChartJSDoughnutController;

      for (let i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        const arc: CustomElement = data[i];

        // determine total radius by diffing outer values
        const radiusLength = outerRadius - innerRadius;

        arc.round = {
          // chart's x/y lengths
          x: (chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2,
          y: (chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2,
          // radius of a single arc
          radius: innerRadius + radiusLength / 2,
          arcColor: arc.options.backgroundColor as ChartJSColor,
        };
      }
    },

    afterDraw: function (chart) {
      const { ctx } = chart;

      // we only expect 1 dataset
      const { data } = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);

      // iterate through each arc's data point
      for (let i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        // extract data
        const arc: CustomElement = data[i];
        const round = arc.round as Round;
        const props = (
          arc as ChartJSArcElement<ChartJSArcProps, ChartJSArcOptions>
        ).getProps([
          "startAngle",
          "endAngle",
          "innerRadius",
          "outerRadius",
          "circumference",
        ]);

        // determine end angle of arc within the donut shape
        const endAngle = Math.PI / 2 - props.endAngle;

        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(round.x, round.y);

        // generate white arc that serves as padding (assumes background is white)
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(
          round.radius * Math.sin(endAngle),
          round.radius * Math.cos(endAngle),
          // twice as wide to smooth out the padding's angles
          props.outerRadius - props.innerRadius,
          // cap should "face" outward from arc's outer boundary
          0 + props.endAngle,
          Math.PI + props.endAngle
        );
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        // generate cap
        ctx.fillStyle = round.arcColor;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(
          round.radius * Math.sin(endAngle),
          round.radius * Math.cos(endAngle),
          (props.outerRadius - props.innerRadius) / 2,
          // draw a full circle for the cap to prevent any spacing issue
          0,
          Math.PI * 2
        );
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.restore();
      }
    },
  },
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Doughnut
        width={300}
        height={300}
        data={data}
        plugins={plugins}
        options={{
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          responsive: true,
          cutout: "90%",
          plugins: {
            tooltip: { enabled: false },
            legend: { display: false },
          },
          elements: {
            arc: { borderWidth: 0 },
          },
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer that you might be looking for but this was my requirement to get rounded edges for multiple datasets. This one rounds off one color in each doughnut dataset.

I used the answer at [Chart.js Doughnut with rounded edges and text centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384092/chart-js-doughnut-with-rounded-edges-and-text-centered/37393862#37393862) and made some changes. Here is the code:

```
        // round corners
    Chart.pluginService.register({
        afterUpdate: function (chart) {
            if (chart.config.options.elements.arc.roundedCornersFor !== undefined) {
                var a=chart.config.data.datasets.length -1;
                for (let i in chart.config.data.datasets) {
                    var arc = chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data[chart.config.options.elements.arc.roundedCornersFor];

                    arc.round = {
                        x: (chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2,
                        y: (chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2,
                        radius: chart.innerRadius + chart.radiusLength / 2 + (a * chart.radiusLength),
                        thickness: chart.radiusLength / 2 - 1,
                        backgroundColor: arc._model.backgroundColor
                    }
                    a--;
                }
            }
        },

        afterDraw: function (chart) {
            if (chart.config.options.elements.arc.roundedCornersFor !== undefined) {
                var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
                for (let i in chart.config.data.datasets) {
                    var arc = chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data[chart.config.options.elements.arc.roundedCornersFor];
                    var startAngle = Math.PI / 2 - arc._view.startAngle;
                    var endAngle = Math.PI / 2 - arc._view.endAngle;

                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.translate(arc.round.x, arc.round.y);
                    console.log(arc.round.startAngle)
                    ctx.fillStyle = arc.round.backgroundColor;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(arc.round.radius * Math.sin(startAngle), arc.round.radius * Math.cos(startAngle), arc.round.thickness, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                    ctx.arc(arc.round.radius * Math.sin(endAngle), arc.round.radius * Math.cos(endAngle), arc.round.thickness, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.restore();
                }
            }
        },
    });
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/n6vLv1zv/

Hope it brings you one step closer.

Comment: if i am doing the same for half circle how would the calculations change ? any idea ?