# Chartjs doughnut chart rounded corners for half doghnut

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I am using chartJS library for one of my projects and I need to draw a doughnut chart. The doughnut chart needs to be a half circle and the sections in it needs to have rounded edges, something like shown below

[image]

I could achieve the same for a full circle by referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446153/chartjs-round-borders-on-a-doughnut-chart-with-multiple-datasets) great answer as shown in the codepen below

[Full circle with rounded edges codepen here](http://jsfiddle.net/ebfgjmc2/52/)

But if I change the options to draw a half circle with following options

```
rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
circumference: 1 * Math.PI,
```

then the calculations seems to go wrong somewhere and the arc circles are placed randomly as shown below

[Problem Code pen here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikhyath/9ruk0eLs/2/)

How can i fix this. Please help. I am stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should change y translation by factor of 2:

```
ctx.translate(arc.round.x, arc.round.y*2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alonas/kx6rjy07/