# Chartjs doughnut chart rounded corners for a cicle with a 3*Pi/2 circumference

Tags: reactjs, geometry, chart.js

I'm working with React and ChartJS to draw a doughnut chart with a 3*Pi/2 circumference
and rounded corner.

I saw these two posts where they explain how to round corners for data sets and it is working as expected with a complete circle and with half a circle:

[ChartJs - Round borders on a doughnut chart with multiple datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446153/chartjs-round-borders-on-a-doughnut-chart-with-multiple-datasets)

[Chartjs doughnut chart rounded corners for half doghnut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64633872/chartjs-doughnut-chart-rounded-corners-for-half-doghnut)

One answer on this post is to change "y" or "x" translation by factor of n, for example 2 in the following case: `ctx.translate(arc.round.x, arc.round.y*2);`

With this in mind I started to change values for x and y but have not yet reach the correct set of values that will make it work.

For example I tried to use a factor of 3/2 on the translation of y and this is what I get.

```
ctx.translate(arc.round.x, (arc.round.y * 3) / 2);
```

[image]

with no factor I get the following:

```
ctx.translate(arc.round.x, arc.round.y);
```

[image]

The code to round the end corner is exactly the same as in the posts I refer. But here it is just in case:

```
let roundedEnd = {
    // @ts-ignore
    afterUpdate: function (chart) {
      var a = chart.config.data.datasets.length - 1;
      for (let i in chart.config.data.datasets) {
        for (
          var j = chart.config.data.datasets[i].data.length - 1;
          j >= 0;
          --j
        ) {
          if (Number(j) == chart.config.data.datasets[i].data.length - 1)
            continue;
          var arc = chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data[j];
          arc.round = {
            x: (chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2,
            y: (chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2,
            radius:
              chart.innerRadius +
              chart.radiusLength / 2 +
              a * chart.radiusLength,
            thickness: (chart.radiusLength / 2 - 1) * 2.5,
            backgroundColor: arc._model.backgroundColor,
          };
        }
        a--;
      }
    },
    // @ts-ignore
    afterDraw: function (chart) {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      for (let i in chart.config.data.datasets) {
        for (
          var j = chart.config.data.datasets[i].data.length - 1;
          j >= 0;
          --j
        ) {
          if (Number(j) == chart.config.data.datasets[i].data.length - 1)
            continue;
          var arc = chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data[j];
          var startAngle = Math.PI / 2 - arc._view.startAngle;
          var endAngle = Math.PI / 2 - arc._view.endAngle;

          ctx.save();
          ctx.translate(arc.round.x, arc.round.y);
          console.log(arc.round.startAngle);
          ctx.fillStyle = arc.round.backgroundColor;
          ctx.beginPath();
          //ctx.arc(arc.round.radius * Math.sin(startAngle), arc.round.radius * Math.cos(startAngle), arc.round.thickness, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
          ctx.arc(
            arc.round.radius * Math.sin(endAngle),
            arc.round.radius * Math.cos(endAngle),
            arc.round.thickness,
            0,
            2 * Math.PI
          );
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.restore();
        }
      }
    },   };
```

These are the options to configure the chart:

```
const chartJsOptions = useMemo<chartjs.ChartOptions>(() => {
    if (data) {
      return {
        elements: {
          center: {
            text: `${data.impact > 0 ? "%"}`,
            color: isDarkTheme ? darkText : greyAxis, // Default is #000000
            fontStyle: "Open Sans Hebrew, sans-serif",
            sidePadding: 20, // Default is 20 (as a percentage)
            minFontSize: 15, // Default is 20 (in px), set to false and text will not wrap.
            lineHeight: 20, // Default is 25 (in px), used for when text wraps
          },
        },
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        // rotation: Math.PI / 2,
        rotation: (3 * Math.PI) / 4,
        circumference: (3 * Math.PI) / 2,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        animation: {
          duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
        },
        plugins: {
          datalabels: false,
          labels: false,
        },
        cutoutPercentage: 90,
        tooltips: {
          enabled: false,
          rtl: true,
        },
      };
    } else {
      return {};
    }   }, [data, isDarkTheme]);
```

Here is where I call the react component for the chart:

```
 <Doughnut 
        data={chartJsData} 
        options={chartJsOptions} 
        plugins={[roundedEnd]} />
```

How can I correctly calculate the rounded edges on a  3*Pi/2 circumference or any other circumference between complete and half?

This issue may be more of a math than programing and my geometrical math is also a bit rusty.

Comment: What is exactly the problem, the rotated amount, or that the radius of the rounded corner does not fit in the circumference?

Comment: if the radius is the problem, seems to me that it should not depend on the dataset length,  as it does in your settings (`a * chart.radiusLength`)

Comment: I think the issue is the rotated amount, as mention the logic works with a complete circle and for half a circle when adjusting the factor of the translate of y by 2: ctx.translate(arc.round.x, arc.round.y *2 );