# Draw rounded edges in doughnut chart in React

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

How to draw doughnut chart in ReactJs using the library `reactchartjs-2` and `chart.js`. The expected chart is something like below.

[image: want some thing like this]

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446153/chartjs-round-borders-on-a-doughnut-chart-with-multiple-datasets

Comment: how to implement that in react??

Comment: The code of plugin is the same as in the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446153/chartjs-round-borders-on-a-doughnut-chart-with-multiple-datasets. To register plugin you do componentWillMount() {
  Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
      // Plugin code.
    }
  });
}  according to this https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2#chartjs-object

Answer (score 0):

I used the code from here: [Chartjs 3 doughnut chart rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72784114/chartjs-3-doughnut-chart-rounded-corners)

```
 <Doughnut
      ref={ charRef }
      className="doughnut-chart"
      data={ data }
      plugins={ [
        {
          id: 'drawСircles',
          afterUpdate(chart) {
            const arcs = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data;

            arcs.forEach((arc) => {
              arc.round = {
                x: (chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2,
                y: (chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2,
                radius: (arc.outerRadius + arc.innerRadius) / 2,
                thickness: (arc.outerRadius - arc.innerRadius) / 2,
                backgroundColor: arc.options.backgroundColor,
              };
            });
          },
          afterDraw: (chart) => {
            const {
              ctx,
            } = chart;

            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data.forEach((arc) => {
              const endAngle = Math.PI / 2 - arc.endAngle;

              ctx.save();
              ctx.translate(arc.round.x, arc.round.y);
              ctx.fillStyle = arc.options.backgroundColor;
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.arc(
                arc.round.radius * Math.sin(endAngle),
                arc.round.radius * Math.cos(endAngle),
                arc.round.thickness,

                0,

                2 * Math.PI,
              );
              ctx.closePath();
              ctx.fill();
              ctx.restore();
            });
          },
        },
      ] }
    />
```