# how to show speedometer on Doughnut chart in chart.js using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I've created a half doughnut chart and wanted to show like a speedometer, but couldn't able to make it. [I have gone through this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990859/half-doughnut-chart-with-chart-js) I want to display my chart Either as similar to the above link or [image: snippet] as per this snippet

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";
import Data from "./Data.json";
const data = {
  // labels: ["Red", "Green", "Yellow"],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [500, 500, 500],
      backgroundColor: ["red", "#FFCE56", "lightgreen"],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ["red", "#FFCE56", "lightgreen"]
    }
  ],
  options: {
    rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
    circumference: 1 * Math.PI,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 70
  }
};

export default class DonutChart extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Sample</h2>
        <Doughnut height="100px" data={data} options={data.options} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is the sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-answer-60873116-yh07f)

Can anyone help me in this query to achieve in this format?

Comment: You may find an answer here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2874

Comment: @uminder - Could you help me how to implement in my sample code, which i have provided ?

Answer (score 0):

Base on the [code sample](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2874#issuecomment-387219952) from [Konstantin S.](https://github.com/knstntn), you could [register a plugin globally](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#global-plugins) inside the `componentDidMount()` method and implement an `afterDraw` function as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
  Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var needleValue = chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].needleValue;
      var dataTotal = chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      var angle = Math.PI + (1 / dataTotal * needleValue * Math.PI);
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var cw = chart.chart.canvas.offsetWidth;
      var ch = chart.chart.canvas.offsetHeight;
      var cx = cw / 2;
      var cy = ch - 6;

      ctx.translate(cx, cy);
      ctx.rotate(angle);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, -3);
      ctx.lineTo(ch - 10, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(0, 3);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.rotate(-angle);
      ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(cx, cy, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
    }
  });
}
```

This expects the property `needleValue` to be defined inside the dataset.

```
datasets: [{
  data: [500, 500, 500],
  needleValue: 580,
  ...
}],
```

Please have a look at your amended [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-answer-60873116-q9n0k)