# 'barradius' for Barchart in ChartJS is not working

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am working on chartjs ( version 2.7.2). I want to create a bar chart having a border radius ( 'barradius' as per the chartjs option).

Something Like this:

[image]

I have set value for `barradius:4` but it is not working.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 2,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};
var option = {
    title: {
        display: false,
    },
    tooltips: {
        intersect: false,
        mode: 'nearest',
        xPadding: 10,
        yPadding: 10,
        caretPadding: 10
    },
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    barRadius: 4,
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            display: false,
            gridLines: false,
            stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            display: false,
            stacked: true,
            gridLines: false
        }]
    },
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0
        }
    }
};

var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas, {
    data: data,
    options: option
});

var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas, {
    data: data,
    options: option
});
```

Also check from here https://jsfiddle.net/anadi/mag91f8k/1006/

Answer (score 3):

As far as i saw in similar problems the solution should be to extend the `Chart.types.Bar.extend`

https://jsfiddle.net/hyacinthe/t8khnL4q/

```
Chart.types.Bar.extend({
    name: "BarAlt",
    initialize: function (data) {
        Chart.types.Bar.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        if (this.options.curvature !== undefined && this.options.curvature <= 1) {
            var rectangleDraw = this.datasets[0].bars[0].draw;
            var self = this;
            var radius = this.datasets[0].bars[0].width * this.options.curvature * 0.2;

            // override the rectangle draw with ours
            this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
                    bar.draw = function () {
                        // draw the original bar a little down (so that our curve brings it to its original position)
                        var y = bar.y;
                        // the min is required so animation does not start from below the axes
                        bar.y = Math.min(bar.y + radius, self.scale.endPoint - 1);
                        // adjust the bar radius depending on how much of a curve we can draw
                        var barRadius = (bar.y - y);
                        rectangleDraw.apply(bar, arguments);

                        // draw a rounded rectangle on top
                        Chart.helpers.drawRoundedRectangle(self.chart.ctx, bar.x - bar.width / 2, bar.y - barRadius + 1, bar.width, bar.height, barRadius);
                        ctx.fill();

                        // restore the y value
                        bar.y = y;
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
});
```

The credit of this answer goes to [@potatopeelings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31610053/6248542).

Comment: ill remove this answer now

Comment: No! there is no need

Comment: okay but im afraid ppl do like -10 downvotes for it. like .... anyway ill let it stay here

Comment: That wouldn't happen, in cases like this, you either mark the question as duplicate or just mention the original author of the answer.

Comment: tried this earlier. Getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined"