# Rounded bar chart with vue-chartjs

Tags: vue-chartjs

Is there a way to make bar chart with rounded corners in vue-chartjs? I googled a bit and found that we can extend Bar chart with our implementation of rendering bars as given in this url -

[How to put rounded corners on a Chart.js Bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582555/how-to-put-rounded-corners-on-a-chart-js-bar-chart)

Is there an alternate way of achieving this function in vuejs?

Answer (score 0):

You actually do it the same way as in pure chart.js

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3072

https://github.com/jedtrow/Chart.js-Rounded-Bar-Charts/blob/master/Chart.roundedBarCharts.js

https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/401

You can create own chart types in vue-chartjs too.