# I want to create this chart -img indescription- in reactjs, which library is the best choice?

Tags: css, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, chart.js

I've tried many times to make this chart but I've failed so i gave up and asking you about it.
If someone can help with it I will be grateful.

[image: chart made with chartjs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This charts looks like a stacked bar chart. This might help:
[Stacked bar chart](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked.html)

or this one:
[Stacked Group bar chart](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked-group.html)

For rounded corners of the bars this one will help:
[How to put rounded corners on a Chart.js Bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582555/how-to-put-rounded-corners-on-a-chart-js-bar-chart)