# ChartJs.Blazor how to change the bar border radius in the bar chart

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, charts, blazor

Iam trying to change border radius to the Bars in the Chart , is there any way to make it in Blazor?

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31610053/5909026

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib the problem that i cant use javascript in razor page ....